# Unbind jquery event works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a fullscreen google maps and then i have a popup. What i want is the popup to dissappear when i click on anything but the popup or if i press esc.

The code below works only one time. I can open the popup and close it but then it won't open again.

```
   var hideBlogContent = function () {
        $(document).on('click', function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).closest($("#blogpost")).length === 0) {
                $("#blogpost").hide();
                $(document).unbind();
                $(document).off();
            }
        });

        $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 27) { // ESC
                $("#blogpost").hide();
                $(document).unbind();
                $(document).off();
            }
        });
```

how can i make it work every time?

Comment: Why are you unbinding events then???

Comment: so that i can open the popup again. otherwise it will hide the post when it opens it?

Comment: You might wanna wrap the functions inside a corresponding wrapper function and invoke it when required if you still wants to unbind everytime but make sure you unbind only the current event , like  $(document).unbind('click');

Answer (score 1):

Use namespaces, [check the documentation for `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to see more.. Currently your `.off()` function is turning off all bindings on the document. But with namespaces you can turn off a specific event binding.

```
$(document).on('click.closeMap', function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest($("#blogpost")).length === 0) {
            $("#blogpost").hide();
            $(document).off('click.closeMap');
        }
    });

$(document).on('keydown.closeMap', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) { // ESC
        $("#blogpost").hide();
        $(document).off('keydown.closeMap');
    }
});
```

Also, `unbind()` here was redundant.